# Хостинг для андроид-приложения

Tags: android, хостинг

Доброго времени суток!
Пишу приложение для андроид.

**Что делает приложение:**

1. Запрашивает данные от PHP-скриптов на сервере, которые отдают их в JSON.
2. Грузит картинки и видео с сервера (пользователи просматривают галерею).
3. Реже производит записи в БД (пользователи пишут отзывы).

**Что хотелось бы примерно в итоге от хостера:**

1. Высокий аптайм и стабильность серверов.
2. Максимально быстрая работа скриптов PHP.
3. Приблизительный объем хранимой информации (картинки, видео) около 30Гб (с возможностью расширения).
4. Возможность назначать привилегии через phpmyadmin пользователям (только чтение БД и только запись в БД).
5. Широкий канал для отдачи (одновременный просмотр более 100 видео одновременно).

Какой хостинг посоветуете?

Comment: Digital Ocean

Comment: Хостер не наш. А вдруг "санкции"? :)

Comment: Тогда такие варианты:

 - взять [вдсина.ру](http://vdsina.ru/);
 - забить на санкции;
 - переехать в правильную страну (по вкусу).

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, вариант только один?

Comment: Да, переехать :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хорошие комментарии на тему выбора хост-провайдера http://ps.siliconrus.com/problem/5699/